# Solve differential equation (Double integral)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

### Problem

Consider the following differential equation, where u = $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$
$$\frac{d^2{f}}{du^2} + \frac{2}{u}\frac{df}{du} = \frac{d}{u^2}(u^2 \frac{df}{du}) = 0$$
And we are to determine a general solution of this ordinary differential equation for $u > 0$.
In short solve for $f$

### My attempt

$$\frac{1}{u^2}\frac{d}{du}(u^2\frac{df}{du}) = 0$$
$$\frac{d}{du}(u^2\frac{df}{du}) = 0$$
Now I'm stuck at integrating it twice to solve for $f$, because when you integrate you have to integrate with regards to a variable, being $u$. So you get:
$$\int\int\frac{d}{du}(u^2\frac{df}{du}) du? = \int\int0 du ?$$
Doesn't the $du$'s take each other out? Leaving us with an integral which we do not know with regards to what variable to integrate from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u^2f''+2uf'=(u^2f')'=0\to u^2f'=c_0\to f'=\frac{c_0}{u^2}\to f=\frac{c_1}u+c_2.$$

Comment: I came to this solution as well, I was just unsure of the notations. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I came to the solution after posting here but was unsure of it as the real solution. You just confirmed that it was right, I thank you!